# Java battleship grid

Tags: java, arrays

In this code I've changed shipGrid from boolean to char.

First, at `shipGrid[i][j] = (Math.random() < chance);` and `if (shipGrid[i][j]) System.out.print("B ");` it says that char cannot be converted to boolean.

I understand that a char cannot be converted to boolean. The purpose of this code is to construct a battleship grid, where empty cells display a "*" and cells with a battleship display the letter "B".

```
int numColumns;
int numRows;
double chance;
int numGuess;
final char[][] shipGrid = new char[numRows + 2][numColumns + 2];
}

public static void generateShipGrid (char[][] shipGrid, double chance, int seed, int numColumns, int numRows){
    for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= numColumns; j++) {
            shipGrid[i][j] = (Math.random() < chance);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= numColumns; j++)
            if (shipGrid[i][j]) System.out.print("B ");
            else             System.out.print(". ");
        System.out.println();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Tutorial on _ternary operator_: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: What are you expecting to end up stored in shipGrid now that it's char instead of boolean?

Comment: You just said you change `shipGrid` to take `char` but this `if (shipGrid[i][j]) ` is the same as `if (shipGrid[i][j] == true) ` so the error is clear. You need to update your condition to check the `char` value and not a `boolean` like before.

Comment: PS : you are using non static variable in a static environnement, this should not work.. What is the value of `chance` ?